# Need Alternation of registerUserNotificationSettings for iOS Version less than 8.0

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I need the code to register UserNotificationSettings in my app for iOS Version Less than 8.0.

I have used the following for iOS 8.0:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the app contains that method (selector).

```
if([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge  | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];
}
```

Comment: How to track AppIcon Badge Number if a LocalNotification is on Repeat?